# laravel not redirecting after authorize fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In  my requests file in laravel 5.2, I'm setting a condition to check if user is authorized for a request or not.

Code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use App\questions;
use Auth;
class answerAddRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        if(questions::where('people_id',Auth::id())->count()==0)
            return true;
        else
        {
            return false;
            return redirect('dashboard');
        }
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'answer'=>'required|min:3'
        ];
    }
}
```

If I do not add `return false` it executes and inserts in a new row, which shouldn't happen, but with the current code it says `Forbidden` which is correct but it doesn't redirect to my dashboard view. How can I make it to redirect to some other page if authorization fails?

Answer (score 1):

In your `request` file add a method called `forbiddenResponse()` :

```
public function forbiddenResponse()
{
    return redirect('dashboard');
}
```

Hope this helps!

---

**Side Note**

Also, just so you know `DB` and `Eloquent` have a method called `exists` to save you having to do count checks with your database so (if you want to) you could write your `authorize` method as:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return questions::where('people_id', Auth::id())->exists();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two return statements in your else block

```
 else
 {
    return false;
    return redirect('dashboard');
 }
```

The second return statement is never reachable.

**Update**

If you want to redirect the user then you can create your custom middleware and write same code as you are doing in `authorize()`.

Use this middleware in routes where you want to redirect the unauthorized user.

Comment: oh yes! so what could be the alternative?

Comment: Is this the answer to the question?